# css spinner animation works at Chrome but not at IE11 and FIrefox42

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a css spinner. It works fine in Chrome, though in Firefox it doesn't work properly and it doesn't appear at all in IE11.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotator {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
}a

@keyframes rotator {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colors {
  0% {
    stroke: #4285F4;
  }
  25% {
    stroke: #4285F4;
  }
  50% {
    stroke: #4285F4;
  }
  75% {
    stroke: #4285F4;
  }
  100% {
    stroke: #4285F4;
  }
}

@keyframes colors {
  0% {
    stroke: #4285F4;
  }
  25% {
    stroke: #4285F4;
  }
  50% {
    stroke: #4285F4;
  }
  75% {
    stroke: #4285F4;
  }
  100% {
    stroke: #4285F4;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 187;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 46.75;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 187;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(450deg);
    transform: rotate(450deg);
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 187;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 46.75;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 187;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(450deg);
    transform: rotate(450deg);
  }
}

.spinner {
  -webkit-animation: rotator 1.4s linear infinite;
  animation: rotator 1.4s linear infinite;
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 187;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  fill: -ms-input-placeholder;
  fill: -webkit-input-placeholde;
  -webkit-animation: dash 1.4s ease-in-out infinite, colors 5.6s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: dash 1.4s ease-in-out infinite, colors 5.6s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66">
  <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4o2unhx0/

Comment: Why reinventing the Wheel? check out font-awesome.css file for full implementation.

Comment: There isn't spinner like this at font-awesome

Comment: Actually you did a very nice job. big like

Comment: @gal did you get this working in IE?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot units for `stroke-*` props. Use %, px, cm, etc. [Check MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972274(v=vs.85).aspx). I think Chrome & FF use default units for it, but Edge don't.

UPD:
So, what about IE? Check this [answer in similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33828560/4336168) and this [Dev Resources](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/csstransitionsanimationsforsvgelements). Your spinner also works (no so good, but..) if you set `stroke` attribute for `circle` element. But only rotate works, because IE can't animate SVG elements.

Comment: Don't help.. still same problem.

Comment: @Gal Sorry, I've test it only in Edge :) I'll try to made it work in IE too.

Comment: Thanks!! i'm waiting :)