# SVG line animation not working in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, svg

I am using a carousel that animates the stroke-dasharray but it doesnt work in IE.

my SVG:

```
 <svg class="facts__svgs" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220" data-facts-stoke-svg="">
 <path d="M200,100 C200,44.771525 155.228475,0 100,0 C44.771525,0 0,44.771525 0,100 C0,155.228475 44.771525,200 100,200 C155.228475,200 200,155.228475 200,100 Z" stroke-dashoffset="651"></path>
 </svg>
```

My JS that changes the stroke:

```
function calculateDashArray(percentage) {
    return (dashOffset * 2) - (segmentOfDashOffset * percentage) - 20;
}

function animateFactsSVG(percentage) {
    elPath.style.strokeDasharray = calculateDashArray(percentage);
}
```

In everything apart from IE this works. In IE the dasharray style is applied but the svg does not change.

Comment: Your question is very vague. What are you trying to accomplish? I've added the code in a web page and started to change the percentage, I see no difference. What is dashOffset? what is segmentOfDashOffset?

Comment: Sorry I will make a codepen now to show my example.

Comment: Here is my codepen example - http://codepen.io/mattclaffey/pen/PNJGRo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken your example and placed it in Internet Explorer and it didn't work. Then I started playing with the various properties to see how I could get to your desired effect. The only way I could make the change in the dasharray reflect graphically was to reset the 'd' attribute: `elPath.setAttribute('d',elPath.getAttribute('d'));` which made the dasharray show as required, but destroyed the animation. Another way to make the changes appear was to add a second comma separated parameter to dasharray, like '1008.58,100%', but it wouldn't create the desired effect either.

I have to conclude that Internet Explorer doesn't deal well with one value stroke-dasharray and you should probably look for another solution.

I actually made it work with a circle instead of a path like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width:100%;height:100%" >
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="green" stroke-width="1" fill="none" style="stroke-dasharray:228,628;transition: all .6s ease;"  ></circle>
</svg>
<script>
    var el=document.getElementsByTagName('circle')[0];
    var circumference=2*Math.PI*(+el.getAttribute('r'));
    function animatePercentage(per) {
       el.style.strokeDasharray=(per/100*circumference)+','+((1-per/100)*circumference);
    }
    setInterval(function() {
        animatePercentage(70);
    },2000);
</script>
```

No animation, though. The value changes instantly on IE. Apparently this doesn't work in Internet Explorer, only Edge (see [SVG animation is not working on IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812303/svg-animation-not-working-on-ie-11#answer-33828560))

Updated the code and saved it in a CodePen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGPwYq

Comment: Thank you. Did you make a codepen example for me to look at?

Comment: I guess if it works with no animation in IE then that would be fine because we follow a progressive enhancement methods so this would be a feature thats works in older browsers but it has better functionality in newer browsers. I tested that method in codepen and what I was trying to achieve didnt work as you can see here - http://codepen.io/mattclaffey/pen/xVPKrM

Comment: Updated the code. I defined the blank space as the rest of the circumference.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this. Worked a treat in IE9 + once I got it working with my code. Nice one :)