# Svg not working in IE11

Tags: css, svg

Hello I have this svg it's working fine in chrome but when I try it with IE it doesn't work. This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/y3k9hntp/1/

```
.svg-wrapper2 {
 position: relative;
 top:100px;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
 width: 320px; 

 }
 .shape2 {
 position:relative;
 stroke-dasharray: 140 540;
 stroke-dashoffset: -474;
 stroke-width: 2px;
 fill: transparent;
 stroke: #c2b6b4;
 border-bottom: 6px solid black;
 transition: stroke-width 2s, stroke-dashoffset 2s, stroke-dasharray 2s;
 }
 .svg-wrapper2:hover .shape2 {
 position:relative;


 stroke-width: 2px;
 stroke-dashoffset: 0;
 stroke-dasharray: 1000;
 }
```

Comment: What version of IE?  Have you addressed IE11s scaling issue? http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: Yes I am trying it on IE11.

Comment: IE11 does not support CSS transitions on SVG content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG animation is not working on IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812303/svg-animation-is-not-working-on-ie11)

Comment: This is a duplicate question please see SVG animation is not working on IE11 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812303/svg-animation-is-not-working-on-ie11/33828560#33828560