# Create line built up animation with hexagon with css javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to create a lines built up animation with hexagon element. I have tried the below for getting the hexagon element styling but with that i cant animate the lines in sequence after each other

```css
#hexagon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

#hexagon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid red;
}

#hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 25px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="hexagon"></div>
```

Any ideas how i can achieve this type of animation with css javascript, jquery?

Comment: How do you want them animated? Do you want the to just pop in? Fade in? Fly in from the top, bottom, left or right?

Comment: Well to animate lines, you would first of all need lines. You don’t have any “lines” here, you have just an element that occupies a certain space. Your best bet for animating individual “lines” is to start by using an SVG as the basis.

Comment: I need to fadeIn top left line of the hexagon then next and so on so all in sequence @UselessCode

Comment: I tried to create to seprate each lines and position them with absolute positioning but that is kind of not responsive solution @CBroe

Comment: In what way do you need it to be responsive? Your initial example just used fixed pixel values everywhere ... Absolute positioning can work quite well with percentage values - but it could be problematic when you need pixel-perfect edges, especially where lines meet. SVG however would have scalability “built-in” already.

Comment: Yes i need pixel perfect edges. SVG is not working in IE that's why am not using it @CBroe

Comment: SVG works fine for the most part in IE >= 9.

Comment: I just tested even on ie11 any animation do not work @CBroe

Comment: Well then use a library that adds those capabilities ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812303/svg-animation-is-not-working-on-ie11

Comment: Thanks for the feedback@CBroe. Will see if that will help