# SVG as a background image does not work in IE

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a `<div>` element inside which I am trying to render an `SVG` image that is supplied by the `CSS` using the `background` property. The code is as follows

HTML

```
        <div id="loading-img"></div>
```

CSS

```
#loading-img {
    background: url(/icons/loader.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

SVG

```
svg width="60px"  height="60px"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" class="lds-progress-pie">
    <path fill="none" ng-attr-d="{{config.d}}" ng-attr-stroke="{{config.c1}}" ng-attr-stroke-width="{{config.w}}" d="M50 35A15 15 0 0 1 50 65A15 15 0 0 1 50 35" stroke="#003478" stroke-width="30">
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" calcMode="spline" values="0 0 0 95;0 0 95 95;0 95 95 95" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" dur="2.0" keySplines="0.5 0 0.5 1;0.5 0 0.5 1" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      <animate attributeName="stroke" ng-attr-values="{{config.colors}}" keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" ng-attr-dur="{{config.speed2}}s" calcMode="discrete" repeatCount="indefinite" values="#003478;#003478;#003478;#003478;#003478" dur="3s"></animate>
    </path>
  </svg>
```

This code works perfectly in Chrome and Safari but not in IE11. Why does this happen and how do I solve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what's exactly happening in IE ? do you have screen shots or can you explain more?

Comment: It renders as a static image. I don't see any animations.

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812303/svg-animation-is-not-working-on-ie11

Comment: IE doesn't support SMIL animations, normally you would have been able to use a js implementation like fakeSmile to workaround that issue, but since you are using this SVG as a background-image, you are out of luck... As pointed out in @Taki's link, IE<Edge doesn't even support CSS transitions, so wouldn't be a correct workround either, which leaves only loading it in an replaced element (`<object>`,`<iframe>`...) or directly in the DOM.